# SQL - #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: sql

Error while trying to import data from one table to another.

[Schema:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqk89.png)

I am trying to import the data from video_games_sales table to the rest of the tables. I was able to import the data to the sales table. But if I try to fill the rest of the tables I am getting the following :

> error #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
> constraint fails (`dwadms`.`year_of_release`, CONSTRAINT
> `year_of_release_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Year_of_release_ID`) REFERENCES
> `sales` (`Year_of_release_ID`))

Comment: Please dont post images, post full table structures inline.  The error is saying you are trying to insert something into a table that does not exist in another table where it has to exist first because of constraints and/or FKs.  So if your Year_of_release_ID  is not in one of your other tables it wont let you insert.  May have to just change the order you are trying to insert so it puts it in the other table first.

Comment: There was only a possibility to put data in sales table. Any other gives error

Comment: You you have dependancy on the table Year_of_Release (without seeing sample data or better design diagrams) this may just be a table with ALL years in it, just sequential years, you may have to just populate that with all years.  Without knowing more cant be sure but that is what is giving you the error, data missing from the years table.

Comment: From the schema, this table seems unneeded/not used at all you could probably just get rid of it (but you would have to examine your app first)

Answer (score 0):

Your error indicates that you are trying to insert data in your `sales` table that doesn't exist in the `Year_of_release` table.

To save data in a table where there are **foreign keys**, you must first fill in **the referenced tables** to be able to fill this **table**.

So, to no longer get an error, you must fill in the tables of this order (according to your diagram):

- game_info
- year_of_release
- reviews
- producers
- region
- sales
- video_games

Comment: Did not work as well. I am getting error while trying to fill game_info table

Comment: #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dwadms`.`game_info`, CONSTRAINT `game_info_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Game_info_ID`) REFERENCES `sales` (`Game_Info_ID`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: What did you do to get this error ? update or delete ?

Comment: INSERT INTO game_info (Name, Genre, Platform, Rating)
SELECT Name, Genre, Platform, Rating
FROM video_games_sales_as_at_22_dec_2016_4

Comment: If there are records in your **sales** table, you must **delete** all the data and restart the insertion in **game_info**

Comment: Also did not work, I am getting the same error even if sales table is empty